# We need use Connection Api, but don't have r_1st_connections permission in our App when we created

Tags: linkedin-api

To add a specific scope to the app that we create, we add a specific product (e.g: Share on LinkedIN, Advertising API ect) and on each of these product we can view the scopes and the endpoints on the 'View Endpoints' tab. I am interested on getting the list of the people I am connected to which can be retrieved using Connections API. This API requires r_1st_connections or r_compliance scope but I can not find neither of them in any of the Products available when creating a custom app. Are these scopes available? If yes, where to find them?

I have tried to find r_1st_connections scope so I can add it to my app but I have not succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

It's under Advertising API product. Endpoint name is `connections`. Refer these docs for further information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/connections-api